# An Autokey Cipher (Now with Added PHP Code)

Tags: cipher

15.26.32.25.23.25.19.11.5.20.3.3.6.12.0.23.4.8.8.8.25.4.43.32.0.3.7.4.3.11.10.18.35.7.4.8.5.21.1.5.58.13.38.3.2.1.62.2.55.10.4.36.14.2.1.3.9.71.59.2.24.13.79.73.14.10.12.3.3.8.65.77.40.75.7.7.74.42.3.8.8.2.4.13.15.3.114.58.32.0.27.5.12.12.51.2.23.12.6.5.10.18.18.7.4.18.7.47.7.32.22.14.5.37.16.2.21.2.0.14.87.5.5.21.58.21.14.8.3.55.8.8.70.42.4.4.3.17.11.3.6.13.13.0.123.5.169.37.16.46.24.13.46.7.113.4.32.7.4.22.49.0.3.6.6.23.10.23.5.20.6.3.6.21.21.4.11.8.37.19.6.1.7.10.45.7.10.78.2.1.43.7.11.4.7.18.4.3.13.9.0.29.4.21.1.43.39.12.0.3.13.6.57.6.15.4.14.82.6.15.27.6.3.14.28.9.5.4.58.5.13.17.10.7.3.7.16.10.5.3.61.7.7.0.99.5.33.5.10.19.4.19.3.132.3.5.31.9.13.4.21.9.1.3.11.64.10.3.85.3.2.298.35.29.56.4.4.7.4.3.2.16.2.16.27.27.3.10.78.8.0.12.5.4.21.36.3.56.3.17.4.4.11.9.41.3.192.4.8.23.81.36.6.14.5.10.3.2.10.35.35.59.4.54.7.15.22.16.2.4.83.17.4.3.14.16.2.30.9.2.7.2.0.20.4.1.3.15.56.4.15.30.5.3.1.9.5.8.10.3.252.6.8.1.393.4.2.176.11.6.29.35.74.6.4.51.18.3.19.10.5.3.9.15.4.84.5.413.9.12.19.4.3.33.78.3.58.7.26.341.18.7.6.19.5.20.15.153

Update: I have decided this will be a better challenge if I show you the PHP code I used:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After writing my own function to decipher this, i get:

> pfailkr atr kppw atrz jvv tjvark. atrwr mji j ojxr pw wpoq-otjnurw urtlyk, ufa ly atr cvppn lyilkr ypatlyc opfvk ur irry. iawlkrw, ijn, jyk nrwwz hfitlyc mlat jvv atrlw iawrycat njyjcrk ap phry atr kppw j vlaavr mlkrw, jyk atry iawlkrw jyk nrwwz mrya ly. atrz klk ypa cp djw, dpw py atr dvppw vjz njyz pvk upyri, jyk ypatlyc rvir mji ap ur irry yrjw atr ryawjyor rborha ipnr cwrja rnhaz ejwi jyk uwpqry hpai.

which, after taking OP's hint at it being a sort of scrambled cipher - and switching some letters around, we get:

> outside the door they all halted. there was a case or rock-chamber behind, but in the gloom inside nothing could be seen. strider, sam, and merry pushing with all their strength managed to open the door a little wider, and then strider and merry went in. they did not go far, for on the floor lay many old bones, and nothing else was to be seen near the entrance except some great empty jars and broken pots.

Which is an excerpt from:

> Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring

Comment: Good work but I should probably clarify, the "alphabet" passed to this function is scrambled... so what you have there is Keyed Caesar :) Very breakable. Good job on your function. Edit: Actually sorry it isn't technically Keyed Caesar but I mean it is breakable in the same way.

Comment: You did the hard work so feel free to copy paste.  [quipqiup](https://quipqiup.com/) solution rot13(bhgfvqr gur qbbe gurl nyy unygrq. gurer jnf n pnir be ebpx-punzore oruvaq, ohg va gur tybbz vafvqr abguvat pbhyq or frra. fgevqre, fnz, naq zreel chfuvat jvgu nyy gurve fgeratgu znantrq gb bcra gur qbbe n yvggyr jvqre, naq gura fgevqre naq zreel jrag va. gurl qvq abg tb sne, sbe ba gur sybbe ynl znal byq obarf, naq abguvat ryfr jnf gb or frra arne gur ragenapr rkprcg fbzr terng rzcgl wnef naq oebxra cbgf.)  Appears to be from LOTR